# Move Images From Parse To S3 AWS

Tags: ios, mongodb, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-s3

I need help moving the images I have from Parse to S3 on AWS.  I have viewed numerous supposed guides and GitHub projects, but everything stops short at giving you all the information.  One even says, you need GCS bucket set up, but gives no details on how to set up one.  Just someone please help me with this.  I have the S3 File Adapter in my index.js all set up for the app, but none of the images are there, they are still hosted in parse.

Comment: Does this need to be a programmatic solution or could you use configuration tools from Parse and AWS? I've written code to download from an AWS S3 bucket, but haven't tried to upload to one programmatically before. It's pretty easy to just use the web interface and drag a bunch of files into your bucket.

Comment: Pretty much a little of all.  I need to get the files moved from Parse TO S3 bucket, and also leave it configured so that when anything is added to it from updated app that points to heroku, it would add the pictures to S3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to old images that where hosted with parse.com that you want to move across to your own environment then it can be done with the utility tool.

> Get all files across all classess in a Parse database.
>  Print file URLs
>   to console OR transfer to `S3`, `GCS`, or `filesystem`.
>  Rename files so that
>   Parse Server no longer detects that they are hosted by Parse.
>  Update
>   `MongoDB` with new file names.

https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils

Moving forward if you have setup your S3 bucket correctly all new images from your app will be stored there.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-File-Adapters

Comment: That is what I'm referring to, however there is nothing in the ReadMe that FULLY walks you through how to do it.  It stops short of helping set up anything with GCS, doesn't show you how to get it all set up, and even the install notes are incorrect as it would not get the git file cloned.

Comment: @user717452 you keep mentioning GCS but you've stated you are going to use AWS-S3 for your bucket of choice. Forget about the steps for GCS if you are not planing to use Googles bucket. The installation works, as the notes describe.

Comment: They supply a config example too : https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils/blob/master/config.example.js

Comment: Installation doesn't work as notes describe.  `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: @user717452  just use HTTPS protocol. Works for me! Public repo shouldn't need SSH

Comment: Ok, so I do that and continue to follow instructions with npm start config.js...and nope...more errors:
`
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-files-utils
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-files-utils
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
`